# Simple sum of finite exponential series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Imagine I have a series such as:

$$(1 + n)^0 + (1 + n)^1 + (1 + n)^2 + (1 + n)^3 + ... (1+n)^x$$

Is there a simple way to summarize this as a function of $n$ and $x$?

Comment: $= \sum_{i=0}^x (1+n)^i = \sum_{i=0}^x \sum_{k=0}^i \binom{i}{k}n^k$

Answer (score 9):

This is a geometric progression. The general formula for a geometric progression is given by
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^{k-1} = \frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}
$$
provided that $r\neq1$.
In our case, $a=1$ and $r=n+1$. Hence,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{x+1}(1+n)^{k-1}=\frac{(1+n)^{x+1}-1}{n}.
$$

Answer (score 5):

$$I(n,x)=\color{red}{1} + (1 + n)^1 + (1 + n)^2 + (1 + n)^3 +\cdots+ (1+n)^x$$
$$(1+n)I(n,x)=(1 + n)^1 + (1 + n)^2 + (1 + n)^3 + (1 + n)^4 + \cdots +\color{red}{(1+n)^{x+1}}$$
we have
$$\underbrace{(1+n)I(n,x)-I(n,x)}_{nI(n,x)}=(1+n)^{x+1}-1$$
therefore
$$I(n,x)=\frac{(1+n)^{x+1}-1}{n}$$